# pyqt getting instanced widgets to work

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to create a gui that lets the user create instances of a preset layout in the gui as shown below. The part I'm struggling with is when I hit the selected button, it adds the selected attribute to the last added widget instead of the one selected. I'm not sure if I'm sub classing correctly or if the way I'm going about it is correct. I've added a note pointing out where I think the issue is. Could someone help me out with this. Thanks!

Edit.
Side note, I'm doing this in maya, but it's not a maya issue that I'm facing.

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

dialog = None
class mainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    instance_count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow,self).__init__()
        mainWindow.instance_count+=1
        self.instance = mainWindow.instance_count
        self.setWindowTitle("Create XML File")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.mainWindowLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainWindowLayout)
        self.layout().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        self.basic_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.basic_widget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.basic_widget)
        self.addAttributeButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Add")        
        self.basic_widget.layout().addWidget(self.addAttributeButton)

    def attributeLayout(self):
        self.basic_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.attribute = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.attributeButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Selected")
        self.basic_layout.addWidget(self.attribute)
        self.basic_layout.addWidget(self.attributeButton)
    def addSelectedAttribute(self,instance):
        objectSelected = mc.ls(sl=True)
        channelSelected = mc.channelBox('mainChannelBox', query=True, selectedMainAttributes=True)
        if (len(objectSelected) !=1):
            mc.error('Please select only one object...')
            return
        if (len(channelSelected) !=1):
            mc.error('Please select only one attribute in the channel box...')
            return
        longName = mc.attributeName('{}.{}'.format(objectSelected[0],channelSelected[0]),long=True)
        self.attribute[instance].setText('{}.{}'.format(objectSelected[0],longName)) # this is where I'm struggling

class MainSubWindow(mainWindow):
    new_widget = {}
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainSubWindow,self).__init__()
        self.addAttributeButton.clicked.connect(self.addAttributeLayout)

    def addAttributeLayout(self):       
        self.new_widget[self.instance] = mainWindow()
        self.new_widget[self.instance].attributeLayout()
        self.basic_widget.layout().addLayout(self.new_widget[self.instance].basic_layout)
        self.new_widget[self.instance].attributeButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.addSelectedAttribute(self.instance)) # and struggling here too

def create():
    global dialog
    if dialog is None:
        dialog = MainSubWindow()
        dialog.show()

def delete():
    global dialog
    if dialog is None:
        return
    dialog.deleteLater()
    dialog = None
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of help from elsewhere and digging about a bit, I realized I went about it entirely wrong as I had suspected. If anyone is curious this is how I fixed it

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

dialog = None
class mainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    instance_count = 0
    new_widget = {}
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow,self).__init__()        
        self.setWindowTitle("Create XML File")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.mainWindowLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainWindowLayout)
        self.layout().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        self.basic_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.basic_widget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.basic_widget)
        self.addAttributeButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Add")        
        self.basic_widget.layout().addWidget(self.addAttributeButton)
        self.addAttributeButton.clicked.connect(self.addAttributeLayout)

    def addAttributeLayout(self):       
        self.new_widget[self.instance_count] = MainSubWindow()
        self.new_widget[self.instance_count].attributeLayout()
        self.basic_widget.layout().addLayout(self.new_widget[self.instance_count].basic_layout)
        self.instance_count+=1

class MainSubWindow(mainWindow):
    instance_count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainSubWindow,self).__init__()

    def attributeLayout(self):
        self.basic_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.attr = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.attributeButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Selected")
        self.basic_layout.addWidget(self.attr)
        self.basic_layout.addWidget(self.attributeButton)
        self.attributeButton.clicked.connect(self.addSelectedAttribute) # and/or struggling here too

    def addSelectedAttribute(self):
        objectSelected = mc.ls(sl=True)
        channelSelected = mc.channelBox('mainChannelBox', query=True, selectedMainAttributes=True)
        if (len(objectSelected) !=1):
            mc.error('Please select only one object...')
            return
        if (len(channelSelected) !=1):
            mc.error('Please select only one attribute in the channel box...')
            return
        longName = mc.attributeName('{}.{}'.format(objectSelected[0],channelSelected[0]),long=True)
        self.attr.setText('{}.{}'.format(objectSelected[0],longName)) # this is where I'm struggling






def create():
    global dialog
    if dialog is None:
        dialog = MainSubWindow()
        dialog.show()

def delete():
    global dialog
    if dialog is None:
        return
    dialog.deleteLater()
    dialog = None
```